# Applying a transition to a jquery .change element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several radio buttons styled so that when you click between them the image changes using the .change function in Jquery. When switching between images the transition is jerky and i'd like to smoothen it out- similar to css .transition property.

I've already tried applying transition styles to all the elements in CSS, but no luck- so it's making me think that there must be some tweaking needed in the JS?

I'd like to be able to style the transition in css so it looks smoother and cross fades- especially when the image changes from a landscape to portrait and vice versa. I'd also probably have more than just two images so it has to work universally for it all.

```js
$('input:radio[name="radioName"]').change(function() {
  var $src = "";
  if ($(this).val() == "1") {
    $src = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1573188747639-2e58493e8df9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1189&q=80";
  } else {
    $src = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522847560429-ad7381e61f96?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=633&q=80"
  }

  $('.slide').attr('src', $src);
});
```

```css
.slide {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="slide" alt="slide 1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1573059225035-dcef0018bcc5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80">

<div class="roman-pagination">
  <label class="roman-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="radioName" value="1" checked>
    <span class="numeral">I.</span>
    <span class="title">The First</span>
  </label>
  <label class="roman-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="radioName" value="2">
    <span class="numeral">II.</span>
    <span class="title">The Second</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

This is a snippet of the relevant code (the whole thing is here: https://codepen.io/albicant__/pen/OJJEpqq)

Comment: I have no idea if this tutorial is still good or not but I found it so I figured I'd share: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-cross-fade-transition/

Comment: Actually, this one is far more concise: https://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/simple-jquery-image-crossfade/

Comment: @Andrew It doesn't quite fit my user case as it's for switching between two images. In my scenario, you would possibly flick between maybe up to ten images so you wouldn't know which image the user would flick to.

Answer (score 0):

For a cross-fade you'll need both images (current, next) in the DOM at the same time. It will look best if you keep the current img at full opacity during the cross-fade then after the transition set it to opacity 0. Have your JS layer the "next" img on top of "current" img (z-index or other). Then your transition class will render beautifully - but the key is having both images there, not just changing the src of a single img element.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how I would be able to do this as I'm not sure what the next image will be as you'd be able to pick from the images at random... unless i'm completely out of the loop here?